# How recursion in merge sort works? How memory will be allocated?

Tags: java, c, data-structures, recursion, mergesort

How stack memory will be allocated?
I can't understand how recursion works here
please explain line that commented "line 4" in the partition function. and explain when this line will be executed?

```
  void partition(int arr[],int low,int high){

        int mid;

        if(low<high){
             mid=(low+high)/2;
             partition(arr,low,mid);
             partition(arr,mid+1,high);   //line 4
             mergeSort(arr,low,mid,high);
        }
    }

    void mergeSort(int arr[],int low,int mid,int high){

        int i,m,k,l,temp[MAX];

        l=low;
        i=low;
        m=mid+1;

        while((l<=mid)&&(m<=high)){

             if(arr[l]<=arr[m]){
                 temp[i]=arr[l];
                 l++;
             }
             else{
                 temp[i]=arr[m];
                 m++;
             }
             i++;
        }

        if(l>mid){
             for(k=m;k<=high;k++){
                 temp[i]=arr[k];
                 i++;
             }
        }
        else{
             for(k=l;k<=mid;k++){
                 temp[i]=arr[k];
                 i++;
             }
        }

        for(k=low;k<=high;k++){
             arr[k]=temp[k];
        }
```

Comment: I don't see line 4jhjklbjkbhkvhjvhyjvhkvhkvhikvgyuvyulgv68ov ;-)

Comment: Line 4 is dealing with second half of your array. from `mid+1` to `end`.

Comment: I know that but how it is executing ?? what will be stack representation of this merge sort algorithm ?

Comment: What do you see when you step through the code in your debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Check this Picture out its a graphical representation of MergSort[image]

First Line is Representing the Original Ary.
Now Partition function will be called. Line 3 will be Calling the Partition function on {38,27,43,3}
and Line four will be calling Partition Function on {9,82,10} and will divide them in Small Partitions and the same function will be called again.
This Process will go on till low < High. In Picture till line 4. After that it will be back and will start merging those partitions by MargSort function.